# Is it possible to be temporarily blacklisted from rooms/hosting in multiplayer Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Sometimes late at night when the rooms are nowhere near full, I find that I am host in TDM games.  In cases where the next map is Wasteland, I tend to exit and look for a new game and almost invariably, I get the exact same set of players and a new map, usually not Wasteland within a second.  However, if I do this more than twice, I find myself not being able to join a room for short periods of time.  At first I thought it was because the room randomly filled up or got merged, but then I noticed that the same players trickled into whatever room I was next placed in, which led me to the conclusion that I might have been blocked from rejoining that room for a short period of time because I kept leaving as host.  Also, I find that when that happens, I am almost always not host for the next match, even with the exact same set of players.

Does this mean that I get marked as a bad host or is it just an 'intricacy' of the IW matchmaking algorithm?

EDIT: I'm playing on PC

Answer (score 1):

MW2 match-making is quite simple, one player is randomly chosen to become the best host of that game, now if you are the host and you leave, the application will have to look-up a new host.

There is no ban system for being a bad host or disconnecting in MW2. If you can't join for a short period of time it means that there are no rooms with a suitable host for your connection. And if you see a lot of familiar names it probably means the lobbies were merged due to low population.

You can get kicked in private lobbies if you join via a friends Steam account that hosts the match.

Comment: I don't think host selection is random at all. It attempts to find the best host.

Comment: Edited now, forgot to specify that.